# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/election/2) on TeX - LaTeX has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Werner]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: Martin Scharrer]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5149632783974400).

Comment: @Werner Congrats and MartinScharrer Thanks.

Comment: Congrats to Werner, he has the skills to be a great mod. Thank you very much to Martin Scharrer.

Comment: Congrats Werner: well deserved! Thank you Martin for the excellent work during these years!

Comment: Congrats @Werner, thanks for taking over my work.

Comment: Again, my sincerest wishes for this new assignment to Werner and also to @MartinScharrer Scharrer who have performed this rule admirably.

Comment: Not sure how internally the website works, but those people (@Werner & @MartinScharrer Scharrer) deserve more than praising.